# Order of join operations on threads

Tags: c, pthreads

My main program creates two threads to perform an operation simultaneously. When one of the threads terminates (i.e. finishes its task), I would like to terminate the other. For now, I have the following instructions:

```
pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, operation1, NULL);
pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, operration2, NULL);

pthread_join(tid1, &status1);
pthread_join(tid2, &status2);

if(status1 == 1 ||  status2 == 1)
{
    pthread_kill(tid1, SIGTERM);
    pthread_kill(tid2, SIGTERM);
}
```

While I join tid1, followed by tid2, in reality thread2 can terminate before thread1 and my program will simply block until thread1 terminates. How can I perform the joins in way that enables me immediately detect one one thread has terminated?

Comment: `pthread_kill` does not do what you think it does. :-) Thankfully it's doing nothing because those threads have already exited, but if they hadn't, you'd kill your whole process.